# Can't start Spoon/PDI after installing my own plugin

Tags: java, plugins, spoon, pdi

I'm developing a new plugin/step for my pentaho PDI installation.

The thing is, that i can't start spoon if the step is in the plugin/steps folder, if i take it out, i can start it normally, so, it is deffinitelly a problem with my step, but can't see anything wrong with it, at least not just by reviewing the code...

I have made some others with no problem, but this one doesn't want to let my spoon installation run :/

Can someone give some kind of input? I know there is someone who had to do a plugin at least...

Comment: could be a permissions issue. maybe spoon can't access it properly and hangs?

Comment: I already developed some plugins, and they work perfectly, I dont have any problem in the code that could be the problem. I have implemented all methods but still, Spoon just won't start :/

Comment: Please, anyone can help me? To see what is the problem, I can't seem to find a way to debug what is going on... :(

Comment: Additional information is needed here, e.g. error messages from different platforms that run this PDI plugin. I assume that your plugin consists of step modules (e.g. Step, StepData, StepDialog, StepMeta) and some logic, perhaps within different packages. Have you developed test classes for the modules of the plugin? Trying to debug a whole plugin without having any clue as to where the problem roots is very hard.